# javascript server under XULRunner fails

Tags: javascript, dom, screen-scraping, xulrunner

I'm trying to debug a DOM scraping packaged called [crowbar](http://simile.mit.edu/wiki/Crowbar). Anyhow, when I run I get:

> Error: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0xc1f30001 (NS_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED) [nsIServerSocket.asyncListen]"  nsresult: "0xc1f30001 (NS_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED)"  location: "JS frame :: chrome://crowbar/content/crowbar.js :: onLoad :: line 375"  data: no]
>   Source File: chrome://crowbar/content/crowbar.js
>   Line: 375

Basically, `asyncListen()` is throwing `NS_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED`. This is weird because the line of code immediately before this is a call to `init()`! I've tried adding:

```
netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege("UniversalXPConnect");
```

just before the call to `asyncListen()` and it had no effect. Is this a security issue? (btw, in case it matters, this is on a Fedora box, running as root, with selinux disabled)... I've also tried a few different port numbers...

Comment: (just to be clear, the UniversalXPConnect thing comes from a google result: <http://www.nabble.com/-FF3b5--nsIServerSocket-doesn%27t-work-td16837464.html>. It's weird and shouldn't be needed.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the source code: http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/netwerk/base/src/nsServerSocket.cpp#369

Are you sure `init()` doesn't fail (that's what initializes `mFD`)? Maybe something `close`s it before your call?

I would [build a debug XULRunner](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XULRunner/Build_Instructions) to build a debug version and/or try to get logging output from the app. Unfortunately, I can't figure out what the `LOG()` macro in that code resolves to, usually it's [NSPR logging](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/nspr/reference/html/prlog.html), but you have to guess the module name in order to enable logging for this module.

Boris Zbarsky (one mozilla core developers) [says](http://www.nabble.com/-FF3b5--nsIServerSocket-doesn%27t-work-td16837464.html):

> Since you're calling init(), the only other way I see to get an
> NS_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED out of asyncListen is for the thread you're running on
> to no longer be accepting events...
>
> So something odd is happening.  Are there in fact multiple threads involved?

Answer (score 0):

I am too facing this problem. I have derived my code from CrowBar and running it through xulrunner 1.9.1 on Win 7.

I get the problem when I am diconnected from the net. If I am on a network it works. I do have multiple threads [multiple  xul elements ]. But I belive I am running it on main thread (I am not sure how I can find  current thread though), so thread not listening should not be the issue.

Also I have noted that in nsSocketTransportService2.cpp thread becomes null, so Boris maybe right.

```
NS_IMETHODIMP
nsSocketTransportService::Dispatch (nsIRunnable *event, PRUint32 flags) 
{

    LOG(("STS dispatch [%p]\n", event));
    nsCOMPtr<nsIThread> thread = GetThreadSafely();
    NS_ENSURE_TRUE(thread, NS_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED);
    nsresult rv = thread->Dispatch(event, flags);
    if (rv == NS_ERROR_UNEXPECTED) {
        // Thread is no longer accepting events. We must have just shut it
        // down on the main thread. Pretend we never saw it.
        rv = NS_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED;
    }
    return rv;
}
```

Hope this helps pin down the problem.

thanks
harvinder